# what is the effect of position absolute on pseudo elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have 2 div's here,using css pseudo elements am drawing shapes.
both are having same proprties except position property of the pseudo elements , how can the shapes are differing in both the cases.

```css
#withpos:after{
border-top: 100px solid red;
border-left: 100px solid red;
content: "";
position: absolute;
border-right: 100px solid green;
border-bottom: 100px solid green;
width: 0px;
  }

#withoutpos:after{
border-top: 100px solid red;
border-left: 100px solid red;
content: "";
border-right: 100px solid green;
border-bottom: 100px solid green;
width: 0px;
  }
#withoutpos{
margin-left:250px;
  margin-top:100px;
  }|
```

```html
<div id="withpos"></div>
<div id="withoutpos"></div>
```

Comment: "what is the effect of position absolute on pseudo elements" No different from the effect it has on any other element. I suspect you're asking about positioning rather than pseudo-elements.

Comment: @BoltClock : what i observed is that when setting position absolute ,its making diagonal proper , where as with out position absolute some spike is coming on the diagnoal.Please modify the question if needed

Comment: I'm not posting an answer because I'm not entirely sure why the absolutely positioned element is not causing the same problem, but the problem in #withoutpos is happening  because when you declared the pseudo element you added an (empty) line of text. This is creating the spike. If you set `font-size:0` it fixes it. Interestingly `height:0` doesn't fix it, however if you set `#withpos:after {content:"text"}` you'll see the same spike but `height:0` *will* fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That additional form in the `#withoutpos` square is due an empty line of text, brought by `content:""`.

This is visible when inspecting the element:

[image]

The after element isn't absolutely positioned so it's push by the flow (this "square" is taller than the other).

As @talya-s says, `font-size: 0` will fix it, and strangely `height: 0` don't, except if you actually put some text (which makes no sense, of course).